# First garbage collector

Tags: c++, memory-management

Today I tried to learn how to make a simple garbage collector for a future project, it didn't need to be fast nor complex nor optimal, it just needed to work. After lots of searching and reading, I was able to make something work.

So, how can I improve it from here? At some point I guess I'll have to ditch the `std::array` (the small size is just for testing purposes). Do I actually need to use `new` and `delete`, or can I just keep using STL containers?

For what I've read, I have a couple options: mark and compact, copying garbage collection, generational garbage collector. Which of them would be the more natural evolution from what I've done?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
struct Handle {
    bool marked {};
    T value {};
    Handle * next {};
};

template <typename T>
class Heap {
    std::array<Handle<T>, 10> heap;

    Handle<T> * root {};
    Handle<T> * free_list {};

    void push(Handle<T> * handle) {
        handle->next = free_list;
        free_list = handle;
    }

    void reset() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i) {
            heap[i].marked = false;
        }
    }

    void mark(Handle<T> * handle) {
        if (handle && !handle->marked) {
            handle->marked = true;
            mark(handle->next);
        }
    }

    void sweep() {
        free_list = nullptr;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i) {
            if (!heap[i].marked) {
                heap[i].value = {};
                push(&heap[i]);
            }
        }
    }

public:
    Heap() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i) {
            push(&heap[i]);
        }
    }

    template <typename U>
    Handle<T> * allocate(U && u) {
        if (!free_list) {
            reset();
            mark(root);
            sweep();
            if (!free_list) {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
        }
        Handle<T> * handle = free_list;
        free_list = free_list->next;
        handle->value = std::forward<T>(u);
        handle->next = nullptr;
        return handle;
    }

    Handle<T> * keep_alive(Handle<T> * handle) {
        handle->next = root;
        root = handle;
        return handle;
    }

    void signal() {
        root = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {

    Heap<std::string> heap;

    auto a = heap.allocate("A");
    auto b = heap.keep_alive(a);

    a = heap.allocate("B");
    auto c = heap.keep_alive(a);

    a = heap.allocate("C");
    a = heap.allocate("D");
    a = heap.allocate("E");

    cout << a->value << endl;
    cout << b->value << endl;
    cout << c->value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want a GC in C++. The C++ resource management is so much better already. WE have fine grain **deterministic** garbage collection built into the libraries (They are called smart pointers). If you want to make the language worse the feel free to add a GC but you should prefer to use the facilities already in the language that make GC obsolete.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm building a scripting language in C++ similar to Lisp and `std::shared_ptr`s won't work if there's cyclic references.

Comment: Then use `std::weak_ptrs` where you can introduce a cycle. That is what they are there for.

Comment: Like, I said, I'm building a scripting language, you can't break cycles if you don't know what will happen at runtime.

Comment: Will you have finalizers, and if multiple ones could run?

Comment: You should take a look at gcpp

Answer (score 4):

From a design and interface point of view, I find the use of:

```
auto a = heap.allocate("A");
cout << a->value << endl;
```

unnatural. I would expect `a` to act like a pointer to `std::string` since it's the value returned from a function named `allocate` using an object of type `Heap<std::string>`.

It would be more natural if:

1. `*a` evaluated to `std::string&` (`std::string const&` if `a` were `const`)
2. `a->` evaluated to `std::string*` (`std::string const*` if `a` were `const`)

Then, you could replace `a->value` by `*a`.

```
auto a = heap.allocate("A");
cout << *a << endl;
```

**P.S.** I haven't spent enough time delving into the implementation of `Heap` to suggest how it can be done.

Comment: I believe that implementing the pointer-like semantics for the allocated objects can be done by implementing the `Handle::operator*()` and `Handle::operator->()` operators.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis, that was my first thought. However, the return type of `Heap::allocate` is `Handle<T>*`, not `Handle<T>`. The internals of `Heap` need to be changed significantly to allow for such a change.

Comment: an important detail that I missed! In my opinion, the added value of the pointer-like semantics does warrant rethinking the `Heap` class. As you recognized before, it feels more natural and intuitive that way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's such a thing as a *simple* mark-sweep garbage-collector.  Many start off that way, but they all seem to grow more complex, particularly as they get tuned for performance.

I'm not an expert in the domain, but I can review some of the C++ style issues.

Firstly, thanks for providing a well-written and complete program with test cases.  That always helps the reviewer!  I compiled using GCC with my usual warnings enabled, and the only criticism it made was an Effective C++ recommendation: class `Heap’ has pointer data members but does not override its copy constructor or assignment operator.  I don't think you need them, so:

```
Heap(const Heap&) = delete;
Heap operator=(const Heap&) = delete;
```

There's a numeric literal `10` which seems to be arbitrary - it seems to be maximum number of roots.  It's probably better as a named constant, to make this more obvious.  You might even want to make it a template parameter of your class.

Loops such as this one:

```
void reset() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i) {
        heap[i].marked = false;
    }
}
```

are (IMO) more readable if written with range-based `for`:

```
void reset() {
    for (auto& handle: heap)
        handle.marked = false;
}
```

You use `std::forward()` but don't include `<utility>`; similarly for `std::bad_alloc` and `<new>`.  Don't rely on your implementation's transitive includes, but always include the documented headers for what you use.  I'd also move the `<iostream>` stuff down to live with your `main()`, as that's really only part of your test suite.

---

My edited version:

```
#include <array>
#include <new>
#include <utility>


template <typename T>
struct Handle {
    bool marked {};
    T value {};
    Handle * next {};
};

static const size_t heap_capacity = 10;

template <typename T, size_t N = heap_capacity>
class Heap {

    Heap(const Heap&) = delete;
    Heap operator=(const Heap&) = delete;

    std::array<Handle<T>, N> heap{};

    Handle<T> * root {};
    Handle<T> * free_list {};

    void push(Handle<T> * handle) {
        handle->next = free_list;
        free_list = handle;
    }

    void reset() {
        for (auto& handle: heap)
            handle.marked = false;
    }

    void mark(Handle<T> * handle) {
        if (handle && !handle->marked) {
            handle->marked = true;
            mark(handle->next);
        }
    }

    void sweep() {
        free_list = nullptr;
        for (auto& handle: heap) {
            if (!handle.marked) {
                handle.value = {};
                push(&handle);
            }
        }
    }

public:
    Heap() {
        for (auto& handle: heap) {
            push(&handle);
        }
    }

    template <typename U>
    Handle<T> * allocate(U && u) {
        if (!free_list) {
            reset();
            mark(root);
            sweep();
            if (!free_list) {
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            }
        }
        Handle<T> * handle = free_list;
        free_list = free_list->next;
        handle->value = std::forward<T>(u);
        handle->next = nullptr;
        return handle;
    }

    Handle<T> * keep_alive(Handle<T> * handle) {
        handle->next = root;
        root = handle;
        return handle;
    }

    void signal() {
        root = nullptr;
    }
};

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    Heap<std::string> heap;

    auto a = heap.allocate("A");
    auto b = heap.keep_alive(a);

    a = heap.allocate("B");
    auto c = heap.keep_alive(a);

    a = heap.allocate("C");
    a = heap.allocate("D");
    a = heap.allocate("E");

    cout << a->value << endl;
    cout << b->value << endl;
    cout << c->value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```